# Отправка файла через http и сокеты

Tags: c++, сервер, http, клиент-сервер, клиент

Есть сервер, реализованный на **С++**, все действия которого заключаются в следующем:

1. Создать tcp-сокет и ждать подключения клиента
2. Когда клиент подключится, то отправить ему файл

Проблема заключается в том, что клиент работает через **браузер**, следовательно, чтобы сервер мог отправить файл клиенту, ему нужно использовать **http-заголовки**. Я не знаком с протоколом **http**, поэтому подскажите, пожалуйста, как должен быть реализован цикл отправки файла (включая **http-заголовки**), если файл следующий - **file.jpg** ?

Comment: Читайте про HTTP протокол. Если хотите понять как это делается.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что клиент к серверу подключается из браузера? То есть, грубо говоря, есть Ваш сервер. Клиент (или клиенты) набирает в адресной строке браузера некотьорый адрес. При этом ему начинает в браузер выгружаться файл.
(Вообще то тот сценарий, что я написал - это работа HTTP - сервера)

Comment: @S.H. Да, Вы правильно понимаете, это действительно работа HTTP-сервера, вернее одной из его функций - отправка файла. Как раз реализация такой функции меня и интересует, а если быть точнее, то реализация конкретно со стороны http (то бишь какие заголовки нужно сделать, чтобы файл передавался).

Comment: Прошу прощения за медленный ответ. Я могу  немного позже привести пример с использованием библиотеки POCO, и ппример довольно прост, так как вся реализация содержится в библиотеке. Но есть более простой путь для того, чтобы "увидеть заголовки глазами": воспользоваться инструментом типа FIDDLER и пронаблюдать загрузку файла с любого работающего HTTP сервера. Или посмотреть то же через wireshark: протокол текстовый, так что всё будет видно

Comment: @S.H. Спасибо, не нужно, я уже разобрался благодаря Вашим советам)

Answer (score 0):

Неважно какой файл, отправляете вы сообщение как набор байтов. Так что цикл состоит в чтении картинки в буфер байтов и вызова send на сокете с этим буфером.

Comment: Да, но при этом нужны http-заголовки, про которые я и спрашиваю

Comment: @ЕгорФилатов так тут HTTP не нужен вообще, достаточно TCP. Если зачем-то надо всё равно вот список полей https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields